# Is "killall -r -9 ." guaranteed to work?

Tags: linux

`killall -r -9 .` sends the `9` signal to all processes matching the `.` regular expression (i.e. it kills all processes).
As it kills itself, the question is, will it kill itself last, therefore doing what it is documented to do, or maybe it will kill himself before finishing the work, leaving processes alive.

Following @David's answer, it means that if you run `killall` twice it has *less* chances of working than if you run it once - because each `killall` can kill the other before it finishes working.

Is this a new paradox, akin to the halting problem?

Comment: you must enable the cannibal option for this to work

Comment: I tested it, but it killed the terminal, so I don't know who was killed and who not.

Comment: lol... looks like a corollary to the uncertainty principle... you can't look at it without altering its behavior (to not kill the terminal, and presumably the processes that own the terminal)

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Someone tried to fix your spelling mistake with an even bigger spelling mistake.

Comment: @hop, try to make sure your edits aren't actually making a post worse.

Comment: @simucal, i usually do, but sometimes the javascript on SO slows down firefox so much, it's impossible to see what you are doing...

Comment: @hop, are you in linux or in windows?  I'm curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The man page says that `killall` will never kill itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
kill -9 -1
```

which kills all processes, in one shot?

Well, actually it kills everybody except init and itself, and of course if you run it as an unprivileged user you can only kill your own processes.  But you don't have to worry about the "order" it kills in: it runs a single `kill(-1, SIGKILL)` syscall instead of iterating over various PIDs.